# Showing errors in modals

Tags: authentication, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm making popup login and registration using modals form Twitter Bootstrap. So I want to do, when someone enters wrong input, it shouldn't redirect to another page, but show this sign_in modal with errors.

So I have this code for popup login:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#login"">Login</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="login">   
 <%= render :template => "devise/sessions/new" %>
</div>
```

Can someone suggest how I can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should activate your modal when login credentials are wrong with the modal JavaScript method: `$("div.modal").modal(options);` where options is a JSON object like this

```
    {
        backdrop: true,      // Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify static for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.
        keyboard: true,      // Closes the modal when escape key is pressed
        show:     true       // Shows the modal when initialized.
    }
```